# Turning the coordinates inside an image into a graph

Tags: javascript, math

I want to rotate the image based on the coordinates of the cursor.
But I want it to rotate more to the left when its on the left side `(e.g. x: 0 y: 100)`.

As you can see the x coordinate is 0 and when on the right side it would be `x: 970`.

This is my code:

`exampleImage.style.transform = 'rotate3d(1,0,0,' + x + 'deg) rotate3d(0,1,0,' + y + 'deg)';`

So when my mouse is on the left side it would barely rotate and on the right side it would.

What I was thinking about was making the coordinates under 485 (halve) into negative number, this way you would get something like a graph `-485 0 485` (see image).

[image]

currently it is something like this:

[image]

Somethings I've tried are:

`var x = x < 485 ? -x / 35 : x / 35;` (35 is just used to make the rotation less extreme).

`var x = x < 485 ? x - 970 / 35 : x / 35;`

I know my question might be a little weird, please let know if you do not understand.

Comment: I do not understand. What is the problem? Any errors in console or you just can't find correct formula/numbers combo?

Comment: I have no errors, but when I try one of the solutions I've tried above, the numbers are not exactly what I want. 

I want my x to be exactly the same as the right side of the graph but then negative. This way the image will rotate the other way when on the left side instead of only rotating when the mouse is on the right side (bigger value).

Comment: Sorry, in short: I think the formula is wrong.

Comment: `var x = (x - 485) / 35` is what you want.

Comment: @Welbog thanks you that is indeed the answer!